# Problema de doble setState con Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

Tengo este código

*choose_interest_screen.dart*

> ```
> import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
> import '../widget/category_button.dart';
>
> class ChooseInterestScreen extends StatefulWidget {
>   static const routeName = "/choose_interest";
>   List<String> _listCategoriesId = [];
>   bool _isAdded = false;
>   @override
>   State<ChooseInterestScreen> createState() => _ChooseInterestScreenState();
> }
>
> class _ChooseInterestScreenState extends State<ChooseInterestScreen> {
>   @override
>   Widget build(BuildContext context) {
>     void handleCategory(String idCategory) {
>       if (widget._listCategoriesId.contains(idCategory)) {
>         widget._listCategoriesId.remove(idCategory);
>         if (widget._listCategoriesId.isEmpty) {
>           setState(() {
>             widget._isAdded = false;
>           });
>         }
>       } else {
>         setState(() {
>           widget._isAdded = true;
>         });
>         widget._listCategoriesId.add(idCategory);
>       }
>     }
>
>     final List<Widget> listCategories = [
>       CategoryButton(
>         label: 'Tech',
>         selected: false,
>         onPressCallback: handleCategory,
>       ),
>       CategoryButton(
>         label: 'Finance',
>         selected: false,
>         onPressCallback: handleCategory,
>       ),
>       CategoryButton(
>         label: 'Design',
>         selected: false,
>         onPressCallback: handleCategory,
>       ),
>       CategoryButton(
>         label: 'File',
>         selected: false,
>         onPressCallback: handleCategory,
>       ),
>       CategoryButton(
>         label: 'Music',
>         selected: false,
>         onPressCallback: handleCategory,
>       ),
>       CategoryButton(
>         label: 'Movie',
>         selected: false,
>         onPressCallback: handleCategory,
>       ),
>       CategoryButton(
>         label: 'Cars',
>         selected: false,
>         onPressCallback: handleCategory,
>       ),
>       CategoryButton(
>         label: 'Bike',
>         selected: false,
>         onPressCallback: handleCategory,
>       ),
>       CategoryButton(
>         label: 'ASMR',
>         selected: false,
>         onPressCallback: handleCategory,
>       ),
>       CategoryButton(
>         label: 'Stories',
>         selected: false,
>         onPressCallback: handleCategory,
>       ),
>     ];
>     final mediaQuery = MediaQuery.of(context);
>     return Scaffold(
>       body: Container(
>         color: const Color.fromARGB(255, 0, 0, 0),
>         alignment: Alignment.topCenter,
>         child: Column(
>           children: [
>             Container(
>               margin: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 30),
>               alignment: Alignment.topRight,
>               child: TextButton(
>                 child: const Text("Despues"),
>                 onPressed: () {},
>               ),
>             ),
>             Container(
>               margin: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 10, right: 10),
>               alignment: Alignment.topLeft,
>               child: const Text(
>                 "Selecciona tus Intereses",
>                 textAlign: TextAlign.start,
>                 style: TextStyle(
>                   color: Colors.white,
>                   fontSize: 30,
>                   fontStyle: FontStyle.italic,
>                 ),
>               ),
>             ),
>             Container(
>               alignment: Alignment.topLeft,
>               margin: const EdgeInsets.only(
>                   left: 10, right: 10, top: 5, bottom: 20),
>               child: const Text(
>                 "Te mostraremos solo lo que mas te gusta",
>                 textAlign: TextAlign.start,
>                 style: TextStyle(
>                   color: Colors.white,
>                   fontSize: 14,
>                   fontStyle: FontStyle.italic,
>                 ),
>               ),
>             ),
>             Container(
>               height: mediaQuery.size.height * 0.7,
>               child: GridView.count(
>                 childAspectRatio: 3,
>                 crossAxisSpacing: 20,
>                 mainAxisSpacing: 20,
>                 crossAxisCount: 3,
>                 children: listCategories,
>               ),
>             ),
>             Expanded(
>                 child: Align(
>               alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
>               child: ElevatedButton(
>                 style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
>                   minimumSize: const Size.fromHeight(50),
>                 ),
>                 onPressed: !widget._isAdded
>                     ? null
>                     : () {
>                         print("funciono");
>                       },
>                 child: const Text(
>                   'Empezar',
>                   style: TextStyle(fontSize: 24),
>                 ),
>               ),
>             )),
>           ],
>         ),
>       ),
>     );
>   }
> }
> ```

el cual es una pantalla para seleccionar intereses.
Cuando se selecciona algún interés del GridView, quiero habilitar el botón *empezar* que está abajo del todo y si no hay ningún interés seleccionado, deshabilitarlo al botón.

Adicionalmente quiero que cada que seleccione un elemento del grid, se pinte en otro color.

*category_button.dart*

```dart
 import 'dart:math';
 
 import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
 
 class CategoryButton extends StatefulWidget {   CategoryButton({
     super.key,
     required this.label,
     required this.selected,
     required this.onPressCallback,   });
 
   final void Function(String) onPressCallback;   final String label;  
 bool selected;
 
   @override   State<CategoryButton> createState() =>
 _CategoryButtonState(); }
 
 class _CategoryButtonState extends State<CategoryButton> {   @override
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
     return GestureDetector(
       key: ValueKey((Random().nextInt(10)).toString()),
       onTap: () {
         print(widget.selected);
         setState(
           () {
             widget.selected = !widget.selected;
             widget.onPressCallback(widget.label);
           },
         );
       },
       child: Container(
         decoration: BoxDecoration(
           color: widget.selected ? Colors.blue : Colors.black,
           borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(40),
         ),
         child: Column(
           crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
           mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
           children: [
             Text(
               widget.label,
               style: TextStyle(
                 color: Colors.white,
                 fontSize: 25,
                 fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
               ),
             ),
           ],
         ),
       ),
     );   } }
```

Mi problema es que yo quiero que haga estas dos cosas al seleccionar algun elemento del grid: que lo pinte al botón del propio grid y que me habilite el botón *empezar*. Y cuando levanto este código funciona muy random: a veces funciona bien, a veces no, a veces solo hace 1 de estas 2 cosas, pero si solo implemento 1 de las funcionalidades sin la otra, funciona de maravilla.

Lo dejo más resumido:

Cuando selecciono un elemento de acá

> ```
>             Container(
>               height: mediaQuery.size.height * 0.7,
>               child: GridView.count(
>                 childAspectRatio: 3,
>                 crossAxisSpacing: 20,
>                 mainAxisSpacing: 20,
>                 crossAxisCount: 3,
>                 children: listCategories,
>               ),
>             ),
> ```

debería cambiar el color de los botones de categoría y después debería habilitar este botón:

> ```
>         Expanded(
>             child: Align(
>           alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
>           child: ElevatedButton(
>             style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
>               minimumSize: const Size.fromHeight(50),
>             ),
>             onPressed: !widget._isAdded
>                 ? null
>                 : () {
>                     print("funciono");
>                   },
>             child: const Text(
>               'Empezar',
>               style: TextStyle(fontSize: 24),
>             ),
>           ),
>         )),
> ```

El problema: o pinta el botón de la categoría o habilita el botón de empezar, pero las 2 cosas no las hace o se pone loco al hacerlo (a veces lo pinta y habilita el botón, a veces deshabilita y despinta todos los botones y a veces funciona bien).

Creo que el problema es que tengo `setState` dentro del widget de *category_button* y también en *choose_interest_screen* pero no estoy seguro.

¿Cómo lo podría solucionar?

Comment: podrías reducir tu ejemplo a algo más sencillo, sin dependencias, para poder ayudarte

Comment: Yo te recomendaría darle un vistazo a lo básico de Flutter y que te leas esta parte de la doc: https://docs.flutter.dev/development/ui/interactive